# Change registry using command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am trying to change registry using command line. Basically by executing the batch or .reg file. I have to change "Shell" value for:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

I have tried "regini.exe" command as discribed on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516 but its not working for me. I have also tried:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon /v Shell /t Reg_Sz /d abcd.exe
```

but still no success.

Comment: I have one application which should change this registry when its launched. Since this is a 32-bit app, if I execute it on a 64-bit windows device, it changes the registry in Wow6432Node key. I was thinking to execute the command line to change the registry so that it will affect the actual target in HKLM.

Comment: What's your aim doing like that ? and did you think that your abcd.exe works as a shell when you replace this value from explorer.exe to abcd.exe ?

Comment: Yes, abcd.exe is meant to work in place of explorer.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't forget to backup your registry first !**

You can use:
`REG ADD [ROOT\]RegKey /v ValueName [/t DataType] [/S Separator] [/d Data] [/f]`

in your batch to change/add registry keys. So it would be:

```
@echo off
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d "abcd.exe" /f
pause
```

For more details refer to:
http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html

Comment: Thanks, it is doing what I have asked in my question. Executing this batch file does exactly what I want. But when I executed the batch file through my application, its again updating registry in "Wow6432Node" key.

Comment: Adding /reg:64 is making the registry entry in exact location what I want. Thanks a lot @RGuggisberg.